# Makefile error: No rule to make target, needed by 'all'. Stop

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I write a Makefile within this directory:

```
    .
├── bin
│   └── obj
├── include
│   ├── globals.h
│   ├── ma.h
│   ├── mb.h
│   ├── mc.h
│   └── md.h
├── Makefile
├── Makefile.save
├── src
│   ├── ma.c
│   ├── main.c
│   ├── mb.c
│   ├── mc.c
│   └── md.c
└── test
    ├── main.c
    └── main.o
```

My Makefile is the following:

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -g -pedantic --std=c99

objs := bin/obj/ma.o bin/obj/mb.o bin/obj/mc.o bin/obj/md.o bin/obj/main.o

all: $(objs)

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
```

But I can't execute with make order; the program gives me this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'bin/obj/ma.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: your c files are inside **src** folder and why **bin** ? you can juste use obj/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell make to map the source file names to object files in some way.  This might work:

```
bin/obj/%.o: src/%.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
```

You will have to do the same thing separately for the `test` subdirectory.

For the missing header file header, you will have to add `-Iinclude` to the command line (preferably in a different variable and not in `CFLAGS`, so that it's still possible to override `CFLAGS` from the command line).

Comment: I used your code, but the program gives me this error message:

ma.h: No such file or directory exists
 #include <ma.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'bin/obj/ma.o' failed
make: *** [bin/obj/ma.o] Error 1

Comment: @faltumd96 Why do you have `#include <ma.h>` in your code?

Comment: I added a comment about the include files.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have any `bin` nor `bin/obj` folder…

Comment: I edited the question. Makes no difference, when the folder exists or when i create it with make